# How to change the label of "Search" key on iPhone's keyboard to customized text?

Tags: iphone, keyboard, key, label

I am using a UISearchBar and i want to change the "Search" key's label to customized text such as "ABC".how to do? thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This cannot be done through the SDK.  You will have to create your own button and overlay it on top of the keyboard, intercepting the user's tap.

UPDATE:
[Search for it.](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=custom+iphone+keyboard)

Comment: Hi coneybeare,how to customize the keyboard? Would you like show me some code snippets?thanks

Comment: Thank you very much,coneybeare,it's very useful to me!